# Firestore transaction produces console error: FAILED_PRECONDITION: the stored version does not match the required base version

Tags: promise, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, angular-promise

I have written a bit of code that allows a user to upvote / downvote recipes in a manner similar to Reddit.

Each individual vote is stored in a Firestore collection named `votes`, with a structure like this:

`{username,recipeId,value}` (where value is either -1 or 1)

The recipes are stored in the `recipes` collection, with a structure somewhat like this:
`{title,username,ingredients,instructions,score}`

Each time a user votes on a recipe, I need to record their vote in the votes collection, and update the score on the recipe.  I want to do this as an atomic operation using a transaction, so there is no chance the two values can ever become out of sync.

Following is the code I have so far.  I am using Angular 6, however I couldn't find any Typescript examples showing how to handle multiple gets() in a single transaction, so I ended up adapting some Promise-based JavaScript code that I found.

The code seems to work, but there is something happening that is concerning.  When I click the upvote/downvote buttons in rapid succession, some console errors occasionally appear.  These read `POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myprojectname/databases/(default)/documents:commit 400 ()`. When I look at the actual response from the server, I see this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "the stored version (1534122723779132) does not match the required base version (0)",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

Note that the errors do not appear when I click the buttons slowly.

**Should I worry about this error, or is it just a normal result of the transaction retrying?**  As noted in the Firestore documentation, a "function calling a transaction (transaction function) might run more than once if a concurrent edit affects a document that the transaction reads."

Note that I have tried wrapping try/catch blocks around every single operation below, and there are no errors thrown. I removed them before posting for the sake of making the code easier to follow.

Very interested in hearing any suggestions for improving my code, regardless of whether they're related to the HTTP 400 error.

```
async vote(username, recipeId, direction) {

  let value;

  if ( direction == 'up' ) {
    value = 1;
  }

  if ( direction == 'down' ) {
    value = -1;
  }

  // assemble vote object to be recorded in votes collection
  const voteObj: Vote = { username: username, recipeId: recipeId , value: value };

  // get references to both vote and recipe documents
  const voteDocRef = this.afs.doc(`votes/${username}_${recipeId}`).ref;
  const recipeDocRef = this.afs.doc('recipes/' + recipeId).ref;

  await this.afs.firestore.runTransaction( async t => {

    const voteDoc = await t.get(voteDocRef);
    const recipeDoc = await t.get(recipeDocRef);
    const currentRecipeScore = await recipeDoc.get('score');

    if (!voteDoc.exists) {

      // This is a new vote, so add it to the votes collection
      // and apply its value to the recipe's score
      t.set(voteDocRef, voteObj);
      t.update(recipeDocRef, { score: (currentRecipeScore + value) });

    } else {

      const voteData = voteDoc.data();

      if ( voteData.value == value ) {

        // existing vote is the same as the button that was pressed, so delete
        // the vote document and revert the vote from the recipe's score
        t.delete(voteDocRef);
        t.update(recipeDocRef, { score: (currentRecipeScore - value) });

      } else {

        // existing vote is the opposite of the one pressed, so update the
        // vote doc, then apply it to the recipe's score by doubling it.
        // For example, if the current score is 1 and the user reverses their
        // +1 vote by pressing -1, we apply -2 so the score will become -1.
        t.set(voteDocRef, voteObj);
        t.update(recipeDocRef, { score: (currentRecipeScore + (value*2))});
      }

    }

    return Promise.resolve(true);

  });

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to Firebase developer Nicolas Garnier](https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-web/issues/25), "What you are experiencing here is how Transactions work in Firestore: one of the transactions failed to write because the data has changed in the mean time, in this case Firestore re-runs the transaction again, until it succeeds. In the case of multiple Reviews being written at the same time some of them might need to be ran again after the first transaction because the data has changed. This is expected behavior and these errors should be taken more as warnings."

In other words, this is a normal result of the transaction retrying.

I used RxJS throttleTime to prevent the user from flooding the Firestore server with transactions by clicking the upvote/downvote buttons in rapid succession, and that greatly reduced the occurrences of this 400 error.  In my app, there's no legitimate reason someone would need to clip upvote/downvote dozens of times per seconds.  It's not a video game.